# Reinforcing Bows in Dark Souls 2

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

Does reinforcing a Bow in Dark Souls 2 increase the damage done while using the Bow with arrows or as a melee weapon?

Comment: Your question has to be **either** about DS2 or DS2SoTFS. It can't be **both**.

Comment: @Mano I don't see why not? [It's been done before](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-2+dark-souls-2-sotfs), and there is legitimate reason to tag both games in a question, like to version differences for example.

Comment: Precisely, afaik the difference between the 2 games is major in many aspects. They fixed many bugs in SoTFS and weapon balance changes have been made too. That's my its crucial in this case to be specific with the type of game.

Comment: @Mano that's my point. The differences between the two games gives people reason to ask about both games at once. Not everyone owns both games, they might have this exact same question about one game or the other; so it would make sense to tag both games to clarify, and if there *is* a difference, there's nothing stopping the answerer(s) from pointing it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you shoot with a bow your damage is sum of AR of the bow and arrow damage.

So yes, if you reinforce a bow your arrows will do more damage to an enemy.